# Server Side program connection details

Tags: java, sockets, socketserver

I have gone through this program which I found in a book for Java. But I have a very basic question to which I could not find any specific answer on the internet.

My code:

I have reduced the code to all what's relevant to my question.

```
import java.io.*;    
import java.net.*;    
public class DailyS    {    
String s="someString";  
public void go{     
try{    
ServerSocket S=new ServerSocket(4242);      while(true) 
   {        
Socket sock=S.accept();        
 //other codes, irrelevant here  
  }   
 }    
catch(IOException ex) {    
ex.printStackTrace();
}    
} public static void main(String[] arg){
DailyS server = new DailyS();

server.go() ;
}  
  }
```

I am aware that the `ServerSocket` will receive a client and assign him some other random port.

My doubt:

When will this program start running and at what point of code will it start running?
I know that java programs begin running from `main()` method. But the thing is the client side program has no piece of code which creates a `DailS` object. It simply connects to the `Server`. The client side program is not calling the `go()` in server side program. So how will the connection be completed if the `go()` doesn't run. Is this managed internally by java?

> Will this request for connection run the `main()` method in DS?

Client side program:

```
import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    public class DailyCS
    {
    public void go{
     try{
    Socket s=new Socket("ip","port");
}
catch(IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    DailyCS server = new DailyCS();
    server.go() ;
    }
    }
```

The Client Program starts running from the main method, creates an object `server` and calls `go()`. `go()` has the code for requesting a connection. But at no point, it creates a server side class object. It neither calls the `go()` in the server side class. Then how will the connection be  completed?

What is the use of `main()` in server side program?

Comment: The client side never connects to the server... It just makes a socket object. And the point of the main method is to run the program. That's pretty simple

Comment: you have to run both the programs. In the server side, the program will listen for connections on the specified port and in the client side, the program creates a connection with the port on the server. Once a connection has been made, the client and server are able to send data to each other. The client and the server side program wont call each other's methods directly

Comment: @Jitin Kodian That means the server side program should be running 24/7. right?

Comment: @MathewsMathai yup. The server has to run 24/7

Comment: @cricket_007 client side reuests a connection and by asking what is the `main()` in servet side, I meant that I am never executing the server side individually.

Comment: What is DailyCS? I see DailyAdviceClient. And that variable in the client should not be named server...

Comment: @cricket_007 I edited it. The class name was supposed to be `DailyCS` .

Comment: Still, variable should not be named server. And yes, in the point earlier. The server runs independently of the client code.

Comment: The server will not assign the client some other random port. @cricket_007 This client does indeed connect to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Networking 101.

A server has an open port "listening" via a ServerSocket. This listens for incoming connections.

A client also has a Socket, but it is an outgoing connection towards the server's socket. A server **must be running and listening** for connections in order for clients to communicate.

This server program is completely separate from the client. They share no variables unless explicitly passed through the socket connection. Just because there are similar named methods and classes, doesn't make them the same.

Both programs need the main method to actually run since this is Java. Both go methods are ran in the respective classes, but only the server socket is actually accepting connections. The client code makes a socket object and connects to the server (assuming the server code is ran before the client code).

Comment: I have one more doubt. How does the program in the server run?

Comment: How will it keep running without a halt?

Comment: The method `ServerSocket.accept` halts execution of the program and waits for a connection. That should be done on its own thread in order not to block other code from running. After a connection is made, then a while loop is typically added to constantly listen for incoming messages from the client.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: The server listens via a `ServerSocket`, not a `Socket` [fixed that for you]. The client creates a *connected* socket in this code.

Comment: So, err, fix your answer?

Comment: @EJP I can only go answer/edit one question at a time! :D Okay, better?